# Writing if statement into ArcGIS Online Operations Dashboard / list options to configure style according to attribute value?

Tags: arcgis-online, html-popup, operations-dashboard

How do I write if statement into GIS operation dashboard / list options to configure style according to attribute value ?

i need to give a different background color to the list results according to attribute value.

[image]

Comment: which GIS are you using?

Comment: operations dashboard for ArcGIS online